# jQuery .append() a pixel on form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, append, pixel

I have a `form` that has an `onsubmit` function call that attempts to add a few conversion pixels to the page using `.append()`.

The form `submit` is firing and redirecting the user off the page before the pixels get a chance to fire (shows as a cancelled request in chrome network debugger).

I have tried a few things with `setTimeout()` etc, but I can't seem to get anything working.

I know I could use an `onclick` event combined with a check for enter key, then submit the form on a `setTimeout` call. However, this seems somewhat hacky.

Also, I do not have access to the page which the form is submitted to. Adding the pixels to this page is not possible.

Is there any better method?

Comment: If you're going to submit anyway, what's the point in adding the pixels?

Comment: Again, what's the point of appending something to a page that is going to be gone in a few milliseconds?

Comment: They are conversion pixels.

Comment: And what's a "conversion pixel" supposed to do?  Again, the current page is going bye-bye when you hit submit.

Comment: I think the best option to track conversion is to request these pixels from the page displayed after your form has been submitted.

Comment: @Sparky Maybe this isn't a question for you if you don't know what a conversion pixel is.

It's a pixel that fires on a conversion event that can be tracked later and analyzed in 3rd party software.

Comment: @pawel

Yes, unfortunately that isn't an option as we are submitting to a 3rd party website :(

Comment: @Matt There might be a problem with the code that is causing it to ignore the false return from your click statement. Append shouldn't cause the page to refresh.

Comment: @MattOgram, a snarky attitude is not welcome here.  You never mentioned anything about "conversion" pixels in your OP, so when somebody asks for clarification, it's a hint to _improve your question_ for the benefit of everyone.  (See very first comment by Anthony)

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for your input, I edited my post to clarify the conversion pixel aspect. Sorry if I came off snarky, it was not my immediate intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option to track conversion is to request these pixels from the page displayed after your form has been submitted. But if you have no control over that page, here goes:

```
$('form').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // do not submit the form just yet
    var $t = $(this), 
        trackingUrl = 'http://placekitten.com/20/10'; 
        $('<img />')
            .on('load', function(){ // when the image loads...
                $t.unbind('submit')  // ...unbind the event listener preventing an endless loop
               .submit() // and submit the form
        }).attr('src', trackingUrl );
});
```

Edit: you should also add some precautions (for example onerror event) in case of the tracking image failing to load, otherwise the form won't get submitted at all.

Comment: Awesome, I think the unbind is the key I was looking for... I will give this a go and get back to you.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `$t.unbind('submit')` will unbind *every single event handler* registered on that element's `submit` event. Although you probably won't register more than one handler, it's good practice to not interfere with potential other plugins and scripts. Instead, you could name the bound function and only unbind that function.

Comment: This ended up working for me, but I used a setTimeout instead of a load event on the pixel. This allowed me to use the existing provided pixel code (without hacking it up in JS):

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue as I was trying to get a tracking (img) pixel to fire once a user   sees a form (but hasnt yet filled it / submitted it). My form was displayed after the user clicks on a button and the solution which was gathered from a number of posts on this site was to add the following script in my code.

```
<script>
function firepixel()
{
trackingUrl = 'http://mydomain/adopt.php?type=popup';
$('<img />').on('load').attr('src',trackingUrl);

}
</script>
```

I then called the function when user clicked the button that triggered the popup form.

```
<a class="button" onclick="firepixel()" href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Here to     Download eBook</a>
```